# Selecting data from MySQL DB using the ID in URL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to pull data in a database from the ID in the URL.

Basically someone clicks on a category link. Then the category name goes into the URL. So the URL looks like this when clicking on the "action" category: `http://localhost:8888/test/category.php?id=action`

I want to then grab everything in the database that equals to the category in the URL - so grab all "action" items in the database which is in a column called "category"

Here is the PHP code I'm working on below. I get this error:
`There was an error running the query [Unknown column 'action' in 'where clause']`

PHP code:

```
<?php
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'test');

if($db->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}

$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
$sql = <<<SQL
    SELECT *
    FROM `games_db`
    WHERE `category` = ($id)
SQL;

if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
}
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo '<h2>' . $row['title'] . '</h2>' . ' ' . $row['description'] . '<br /><br />';
}


echo 'Total results: ' . $result->num_rows;

// Free result set
mysqli_free_result($result);

mysqli_close($db);
?>
```

Comment: it needs to be `"$id"`, not `($id)` so it compares against a string, otherwise it treats it as a column name. also, obligatory comment about not using `mysql_*`, and although it's good to see you're escaping the parameters -- prepared statements would be better again.

Comment: you're mixing APIs, this will never fire up `mysql_real_escape_string`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing MySQL functions with `mysql_real_escape_string()`, which doesn't work with any other API than its own.

- Use its `mysqli_` equivalent `mysqli_real_escape_string()`, which requires a DB connection.

Then quote the `$id` variable in the query, and not use brackets.

```
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_GET['id']);
$sql = <<<SQL
    SELECT *
    FROM `games_db`
    WHERE `category` = '$id'
SQL;
```

- Sidenote: `"$id"` will also work.

---

Reference(s):

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php